Build a slanted pyramid with ten L-shaped blocks
Consider the following L-shaped 3-dimensional object made up of three unit cubes joined at their faces:

Use 10 of the above L-shaped pieces to make the following shape:




 Yes, it is possible:

 Each line below gives (x,y,z) coordinates
 of the 3 unit cubes of an L-shaped block.
 The origin (0,0,0) is at the red corner
 unit cube not visible in the diagram.

 ((1, 3, 0), (0, 3, 0), (1, 2, 0))

 ((0, 2, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0))

 ((3, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 1, 0))

 ((2, 2, 1), (1, 2, 1), (2, 2, 0))

 ((0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1))

 ((1, 1, 2), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 1))

 ((1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1))

 ((2, 1, 1), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0))

 ((3, 3, 0), (2, 3, 0), (3, 2, 0))

 ((0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 3))



Here’s my solution:

 

 Click/tap on above image to see a larger view of pyramid.

